# Flowtype (/React) optional props as type/enum

Tags: reactjs, enums, react-native, flowtype

Can I have a property in Props which is optional and defined as a type. Currently I get the error: 'This type is incompatible with MyDefinedEnum'

My code:

```
type MyDefinedEnum = 'light' | 'dark';

type Props = { 
    keyboardType?: MyDefinedEnum,
};

class InputField extends Component<void, Props, void> {
    ....
}
```

when I use this component in another view as follows:

```
class Login extends Component {
    ....
    render() {
       return (
           <Input />;
       )
}
```

I get the above error (This type is incompatible with MyDefinedEnum)

Comment: Can you add the exact/complete error message you are getting to your question?

Comment: @elevine This type is incompatible with MyDefinedEnum(union: string literal 'light' | string literal 'dark')

Comment: @AngeloA Why don't you define `Props` s.t.

`type Props = { keyboardType?: 'light' | 'dark'};`
If it's optional, you have to define `defaultProps`.
`type DefaultProps = { keyboardType: 'light'};`
Then use it like
`class InputField extends Component<DefaultProps, Props, void> {`